# What is the correct URL to make available the FAB feature in karafe?

Tags: apache-servicemix, fuseesb

At http://fuse.fusesource.org/bundle/faq.html#How_do_I_enable_FAB_support_in_my_OSGi_container_, we are instructed to do:

```
features:addUrl mvn:org.fusesource.fuse/fuse-fuse/7.0.1.fuse-084/xml/features
features:install fuse-bundle
```

in karafe to enable FAB. This results in:

```
Could not add Feature Repository:
java.lang.RuntimeException: URL [mvn:org.fusesource.fuse/fuse-fuse/7.0.1.fuse-084/xml/features] could not be resolved.
Please verify that the feature repository URL is correct and that your network connection works fine.
```

Can anybody advise us as to what URL we should use and where to find such information on an ongoing basis? Also, where, more generally, is the official place to look for such documentation. I have not found RedHat's stewardship terribly helpful in that regard.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the maven repository to your Apache Karaf configuration file. See the etc directory, there is a file org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg where you add the fusesource repo where the FAB distribution is.

Notice that its much easier to use JBoss Fuse or Fuse ESB Enterprise, as they have FAB enabled out of the box.

The repo url is: http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases

So in etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg file you add this line to the repos in the bottom of the file:

```
http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases@id=fusesource.release.repo, \
```

Comment: OK, thanks. But it's the repository URL that I'm inquiring about. I may use FUSE ESB, but I need the most up-to-date code. Would that be from servicemix or FUSE? In particular, there's a bug fix in the fop feature that I'm also trying to get installed. Thanks.